# Why doesn't a string literal vanish after going out of scope?

Tags: rust

Shouldn't `test` vanish after going out of the scope? Why can `println!` still print the value of `test`?

```
fn skip<'a>(line: &'a str, _prefix: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    line
}

fn main() {
    let line = "aaa";
    let q;
    {
        let test = "bbb";
        q = skip(test, line);
    }
    println!("{}", q);
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: a literal has a static lifetime, so `'a` is inferred to be `'static` in `skip`.